# Using font awesome - regular icons in latex

Tags: latex

I'm currently using `\faEnvelope` and `\faMobile` as icons in my resume, but they're too dark. I can see in this `fontawesome5` [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf) they have "regular" icons as well which is what I want to use.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\urlstyle{same}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    {\LARGE \textbf {Shawn}} \\ \vspace{4pt}
    \small \href{https://shawnmitchell01.github.io/}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faGlobe\ {shawnmitchell01.github.io}}  ~
 \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/shawnmitchell01/}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faLinkedin\ {linkedin.com/in/shawnmitchell01}}  ~
    \href{https://github.com/shawnmitchell01}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faGithub\ {github.com/shawnmitchell01}} \\[4pt]
 \faMobile\ 67809912 \href{mailto:shawnmitchell01@gmail.com}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}\faEnvelope[regular]\ {shawnmitchell01@gmail.com}}
    \vspace{-8pt}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there in the documentation you linked. The default style is solid. If you want to use another style, you just have to specify it right after the icon name.

In this case, if you want to use the `regular` style, instead of just `\faEnvelope` you have to use `\faEnvelope[regular]`.

Comment: I tried it ofcourse. When I use pdflatex, I get the icon followed by [regular]

Comment: @TonyStark do make sure you are loading `fontawesome5` and not `fontawesome`

Comment: @TonyStark This works fine: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\faEnvelope[regular]

\end{document}`

Comment: @TonyStark `\href{mailto:shawnmitchell01@gmail.com}{\raisebox{-0.2\height}{\faEnvelope[regular]}\ {shawnmitchell01@gmail.com}}`

Comment: @TonyStark `\raisebox` does have two mandatory arguments. The second one is missing in your example.

Comment: I had to enclose it within `{}` like you did, this is embarrassing haha. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, my alignment was a bit off too, that should be the reason. I understand `\raisebox` has 2 arguments, thanks a lot @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz!!!